# Ficar atualizando a imagem no tkinter Label com if

Tags: python, tkinter

estou tentando fazer uma simples visualização gráfica da direção do vento mas não estou conseguindo. Este é meu codigo simplificado apenas com 2 if's:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import serial.tools.list_ports


ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for p in ports:
    if 'CH340' or 'Arduino' in p.description:        
        s = serial.Serial(p.device)
        s.baudrate = 9600

#Chamado principal do programa
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed') #Tela cheia com os bot�es para fechar, minimizar.

def checkSerialPort():
    global recentPacket
    global recentPacketString
    global nonumber
    global s
    if s.isOpen(): #and s.in_waiting:
        recentPacket = s.readline()
        recentPacketString = recentPacket.decode('ISO-8859-1').rstrip('\n')

        try:
            textorosa.set(recentPacketString)
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, IndexError):
            pass
        textorosaEntry.after(100, checkSerialPort)
        return recentPacketString


basewidth_1 = 309


#--------------------------------------------------------------------

caixadarosa = tk.LabelFrame(root, text=' VENTO PREDOMINANTE ', font=("Arial",14, "bold"))
caixadarosa.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)

textorosa = tk.StringVar()
textorosaEntry = ttk.Entry(caixadarosa, width=27, textvariable=textorosa, state='readonly', font=("Arial",18), justify='center', foreground='blue' )
textorosaEntry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='W')

checkSerialPort()


if "Norte" in recentPacketString:
    img = Image.open("WindCompass/N.png")
    wpercent = (basewidth_1 / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth_1, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imgLabel = tk.Label(caixadarosa, image=img).grid(column=2, row=2)


elif "Nordeste" in recentPacketString:
   img = Image.open("WindCompass/NE.png")
   wpercent = (basewidth_1 / float(img.size[0]))
   hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
   img = img.resize((basewidth_1, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
   imgLabel = tk.Label(caixadarosa, image=img).grid(column=2, row=0)




root.mainloop()
```

Como pode ver pelo codigo minimo, eu pego o valor do *recentPacketString* e jogo no Entry e fica atualizando sozinho, inicialmente, eu tive dificuldade de achar uma solução para pegar o valor do *recentPacketString* fora da função para usar no if já que eu não conseguir pegar os valores do proprio Entry mas dei um jeitinho de pegar fora do Entry (não sei se foi da melhor forma, sou completamente iniciante no python).

Agora o problema que eu gostaria de resolver e se é possivel resolver é que quando esse *recentPacketString* for gerando valores(Norte, Nordeste e etc.) o if vai rodando no loop checando esses valores e vá também mudando as imagens.

Alguem tem uma ideia de como resolver o problema?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tive uma iluminação divina graças tanto ao comentario do amigo @Tanukaum e comecei a pesquisar e fui associando. O codigo ficou assim:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import serial.tools.list_ports


ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for p in ports:
    if 'CH340' or 'Arduino' in p.description:        #(Codigo adaptado)Dependendo do Arduino vai mudar o if de 'Arduino' para 'CH340' ou vice versa.
        s = serial.Serial(p.device)
        s.baudrate = 9600

#Chamado principal do programa
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed') #Tela cheia com os bot�es para fechar, minimizar.

def checkSerialPort():
    global recentPacket
    global recentPacketString
    global nonumber
    global s
    if s.isOpen(): #and s.in_waiting:
        recentPacket = s.readline()
        recentPacketString = recentPacket.decode('ISO-8859-1').rstrip('\n')
        #serialArduino.insert("end", recentPacketString + '\n')
        #nonumber = re.findall('[\d]*[.][\d]+|[\d]+', recentPacketString)
        #serialArduino.see("end")
        try:
            textorosa.set(recentPacketString) #Se tiver mais de um numero e a velocidade for o primeiro coloca [0] no final, se a velocidade for o segundo numero usa [1]
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, IndexError):
            pass
        textorosaEntry.after(100, checkSerialPort)
        print(recentPacketString)

basewidth_1 = 309
# direcao = "sudoeste"
# graus = 2


#--------------------------------------------------------------------

caixadarosa = tk.LabelFrame(root, text=' VENTO PREDOMINANTE ', font=("Arial",14, "bold"))
caixadarosa.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)

textorosa = tk.StringVar()
textorosaEntry = ttk.Entry(caixadarosa, width=27, textvariable=textorosa, state='readonly', font=("Arial",18), justify='center', foreground='blue' )
textorosaEntry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='W')

checkSerialPort()

img = Image.open("WindCompass/N.png")
wpercent = (basewidth_1 / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth_1, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

imgLabel = tk.Label(caixadarosa, image=img)
imgLabel.grid(column=2, row=2)

def MudarImagem():

    if "Norte" in recentPacketString:
        img = Image.open("WindCompass/N.png")
        wpercent = (basewidth_1 / float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth_1, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        #imgLabel.grid_forget()
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        imgLabel.configure(image=img2)
        imgLabel.image = img2



    elif "Nordeste" in recentPacketString:
       img = Image.open("WindCompass/NE.png")
       wpercent = (basewidth_1 / float(img.size[0]))
       hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
       img = img.resize((basewidth_1, hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

       img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
       imgLabel.configure(image=img)
       imgLabel.image = img

    imgLabel.after(100, MudarImagem)

MudarImagem()

root.mainloop()
```

Coloquei uma imagem inicial só para não ficar sem imagem e criei uma função e joguei os ifs dentro dela, usei .configure e .img dentro dos ifs em vez de chamar a label novamente e no final trabalhei em cima do .after para ela atualizar.

Answer (score -2):

Usa `grid_forget()`, no label que contém a imagem antes de trocar de imagem.

Comment: Em todos então? Não sabia desse forget, vou pesquisar melhor e ver como posso aplicar ele, obrigado pela dica depois venho aqui dizer se solucionou ou se encontrei solução

Comment: Infelizmente o que eu tentei não funcionou.
Vendo outros exemplos e depois de algumas pesquisas, coloquei o label para fora e utilizei configure junto o forget mas não esta atualizando sozinho.